# Find the Mocked module source code in protractor for Debugging purpose

Tags: angularjs, webpack, protractor

I have a web application build with Webpack. The application I created uses angularjs. When I usually load the application in Chrome and open developer tools, I usually find the source scripts under **webpack://** -> **.** -> **app/scripts** in **chrome dev tools**.

I can find my controllers, services and all my script files there. I am now writing protractor tests for E2E on Chrome and am mocking the backend calls.

```
describe('signOnApp E2E test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    browser.addMockModule('signOnApp', function() {
      angular.module('signOnAppE2E', ['signOnApp', 'ngMockE2E'])
        .run(function($httpBackend,$http) {
           var dummyResponse = {"setting1": "value1",
           "setting2": "value2"}
           httpBackend.whenGET("/signOnApp/config/config.json").respond(200, dummyResponse); 
    });
    });
  });

  it('should load the page after loading from config', function() {
    browser.get('http://localhost:4321/signonApp.html');
    browser.enterRepl();
 });
})
```

When I run protractor test, I see that the page is loading and the call that I am making is not actually getting served by the mocked code. Hence I get a 404 error. Now when I open DevTools, I don't even see my code in sources. My angular app is **manually bootstrapped** and I did not use `ng-app` directive.

> Am my missing something when I lookup my mocked code in chrome dev tools?

Comment: Do you have `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;` set?